# tcl/tk on mac os, Python IDLE won't start and Macports not working properly

Tags: macos, mac

Earlier, I was playing around with Homebrew, Macports and Active State TCL/TK after I got the new Mac Pro. But somehow I accidentally deleted the tcl/tclsh folder when I was trying to delete the active state version of tcl.

Now the problem is, when I'm trying to install MongoDB with Macports using:

```
sudo port install mongodb
```

It give me an error saying:

```
/usr/bin/tclsh: no such file or directory
```

so I guess I deleted the wrong file.  Is there any way I can get it back? I tried installing tcl/tk using the Active State package but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my installation of 10.8 `/usr/bin/tclsh` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/tclsh8.5`, which is a symlink to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/tclsh8.5`.

```
$ stat -f%Y /usr/bin/tclsh
tclsh8.5
$ stat -f%Y /usr/bin/tclsh8.5
../../System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/tclsh8.5
```

If you deleted other files, you can use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract files from an OS X installer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm new to the unix system this really took me a while to figure out. I almost went to recovery mode.